# array of byte absolute String: incorrect content while compiling for 64-bit-Windows

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe5

If I compile for 64-bit-Windows my Byte-Arrays haven't got the correct Input-Values.
If I compile this procedure for x32-Windows the values are correct.

Can anyone help me?

```
procedure doAnything(AText: String); //for example "<xml><s name="hello"/></xml>"
var
  myArray:array of Byte absolute AText;
begin
  ... (* myArray for x32: correct Length and Values (60, 0, 120, 0, 109, 0, ...) *)
  ... (* myArray for x64: Length: 2 (60, 0) *)
end
```

Comment: This code is wrong in all Delphi versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access the character data of a `String` as raw bytes, you have to use a type-cast instead, **DO NOT** use `absolute` as the memory layout of a `String` and a dynamic array are not compatible, as others have pointed out to you:

```
procedure doAnything(AText: String);
var
  myBytes: PByte;
  myBytesLen: Integer;
begin
  myBytes := PByte(PChar(AText));

  myBytesLen := ByteLength(AText);
  // or: myBytesLen := Length(AText) * SizeOf(Char);

  // use myBytes up to myBytesLen as needed...
end;
```

If you really wanted to use `absolute`, you would have to use it more like this instead:

```
procedure doAnything(AText: String);
var
  myChars: PChar;
  myBytes: PByte absolute myChars;
  myBytesLen: Integer;
begin
  myChars := PChar(AText);

  myBytesLen := ByteLength(AText);
  // or: myBytesLen := Length(AText) * SizeOf(Char);

  // use myBytes up to myBytesLen as needed...
end;
```

Answer (score 7):

The memory layout for a string is not the same as a dynamic array.
Using the `absolute` keyword here is plain wrong.
In 32 bit it happens that the length is read correctly, but the value is in characters, not in bytes.

You can do something like this to access the string as bytes:

```
procedure doAnything(AText: String); //for example "<xml><s name="hello"/></xml>"
var
  pB : PByte;
  i,len : Integer;
begin
  pB := Pointer(AText);
  len := Length(AText)*SizeOf(Char);
  for i := 1 to len do
  begin
    WriteLn(pB^);
    Inc(pB);
  end;
  // Or 
  for i := 0 to len-1 do
  begin
    WriteLn(pB[i]);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, the problem is that you are mapping apples and pears in the 64 bit world. If you look at this:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Internal_Data_Formats#Dynamic_Array_Types

And the string:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Internal_Data_Formats#Long_String_Types

You will see that the lengths have a different number of bytes for these two. The offsets also don't match. Basically they are not compatible.